# Why does Android Studio 1.2 use ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to Android programming. I have installed `Android Studio 1.2.1.1`.
I created a new project with `min SDK = API 17` and `target SDK = API 22`.

Studio automatically extends `MainActivity` etc. with `ActionBarActivity` even through this is deprecated.

I have done some reading and now know how to change the code to use **"extends Activity" or even "extends AppCompatActivity"**.

Why is Android Studio using this? 
I am not even trying to build for very old SDK versions.

Comment: You will need to do it manually for now. Maybe it will default to AppCompatActivity in the future release of Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio uses application templates, I simply believe it wasn't updated yet. (You can create your own templates, if you want to)

Comment: Thanks to both.
@Leandros I will search for how to create templates, unless you would like to give me a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update to the Canary version, it will use `AppCompatActivity`.